# How to make cucumber report in jenkins paralell pipeline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jenkins, cucumber, jenkins-pipeline

I use Jenkins pipeline for running my cucumber test in parallel using knapsack. I wont make beautiful test report, I try use Cucumber report plugin, but I don't understand how it use with parallel pipeline. I have tried put `cucumber **/*.json` in different places in pipeline but nothing happens. Meybe someone can explain hot it use or can show pipeline where it's works? Thanks.

Here is my pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage ('Build frontend') {
            steps {
                sh('bash -lc "./jenkins-prepare.sh cucumber"')
            }
        }

        stage ('Stash files') {
            steps {
                stash 'source'
            }
        }

        stage ('Set sha in variable') {
            steps {
                script {
                    gitCommit = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git rev-parse HEAD').trim()
                }
            }
        }

        stage ('Test') {
            steps {
                script {
                    parallel(
                        knapsack(6) {
                            node {

                            ansiColor('xterm') {
                                unstash 'source'
                                sh('bash -lc "./jenkins-test.sh cucumber"')
                                }
                             }

                         }
                    )
                }
            }
        }

    }
}


def knapsack(ci_node_total, cl) {
    def nodes = [:]
    for(int i = 0; i < ci_node_total; i++) {
        def index = i
        nodes["ci_node_${i}"] = {
            withEnv(["CI_NODE_INDEX=$index", "CI_NODE_TOTAL=$ci_node_total"]) {
                cl()
            }
        }
    }
    return nodes;
}
```

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42756111/need-help-on-cucumberreportpublisher-in-jenkins-pipeline-workflow can help you configure the CucumberReportPublisher.